# Time to process a file is very long without import

Tags: python, file, runtime

My code is as follows:

```
import re

def get_filename():
    """gets the file"""
    filename = input("Please enter filename: ")
    return filename
    
def get_words_from_file(filename):
    """getting the data and printing it word by word"""
    infile = open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
    outfile = infile.read().splitlines()
    words = []
    reading = False
    for let in outfile:
        if let.startswith("*** START OF")and reading == False:
            reading = True
        elif let.startswith("*** END OF SYNTHETIC TEST CASE ***") or let.startswith("*** END"):
            return words
        elif reading:
            let = let.lower()
            words.extend(re.findall("[a-z]+[-'][a-z]+|[a-z]+[']?|[a-z]+", let))
    return words

def calculate(words):
    """gjhwjghwg2"""
    all_times = []
    max_word_length = 0
    number_of_words = len(words)
    average = sum(len(word) for word in words) / number_of_words
    for word in words:
        if len(word)>max_word_length:
            max_word_length=len(word)
    for word in words:
        total =words.count(word)
        all_times.append(total)
    max_frequency = max(all_times)
    
    result = (number_of_words, average, max_word_length, max_frequency)
    return result

def print_results(stats_tuple):
    """calculate the goods"""
    (number_of_words, average, max_word_length, max_frequency) = stats_tuple
    print("")
    print("Word summary (all words):")
    print(" Number of words = {0}".format(number_of_words))
    print(" Average word length = {:.2f}".format(average))
    print(" Maximum word length = {0}".format(max_word_length))
    print(" Maximum frequency = {0}".format(max_frequency))

def main():
    """ghkghwgjkwhgw"""
    filename = get_filename()
    data = get_words_from_file(filename)
    stats = calculate(data)
    print_results(stats)
main()
```

I have a text file that is very large so when I try and run it, it takes a very long time. Just wondering if there is something I need to change in order for it to not take as long. The code works fine elsewhere but this text file has 75,000 words.

Comment: Did you measure which part of the code takes the most time? Of course you could do something like `max_word_length = len(max(words, key=len))` to get the max word length, but that doesn't seem to be the slow part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see I would assume that

```py
    for word in words:
        total =words.count(word)
        all_times.append(total)
```

is the problem, because its runtime is O(len(words)**2). What about changing this to

```py
    frequency = {word: 0 for word in words}
    for word in words:
        frequency[word] += 1
    max_frequency = max(frequency.values())
```

Note: I did not test this code.

Comment: An alternative to the definition of the frequency dictionary: Use a `defaultdict` with `from collections import defaultdict` and define `frequency = defaultdict(int)`.

Answer (score 0):

In `get_words_from_file`:

- do not read the whole file and then split lines - just iterate over the lines
- compile your regex pattern once and use it
- do you really need that `lower()` call?

Comment: While I agree that each of these points is a good idea, I doubt that changing it will solve his problem. Both his and your ways have runtime linear in the number of words or file size and with only 75k words, memory should not be a great issue here. If I remember correctly, explicitly compiling the regex here will hardly make any difference since python caches compiled regexs anyway.

Comment: I totally agree with you. My points are more 'good habits' than specific solutions to this particular case. And thanks for recalling the regex caching, I totally forgot about it

Answer (score -1):

You have a text file with N-words. You are iterating over it 5 times

1. get_words_from_file
2. average = sum(len(word) for word in words) / number_of_words

```py
3)  for word in words:
        if len(word)>max_word_length:
            max_word_length=len(word)
```

```py
4)  for word in words:        
        total =words.count(word) # here is the fifth time
        all_times.append(total)
```

All and all, your time complexity is 2N+N^2; O(N^2).

You can save a lot of time by doing only two iterations.
In the first iteration over the words, make a dictionary of key=the word value=number of appearances

```py
dict[str,int]
```

And the second iteration will be to calculate all the other measures.

In the worse case (if all the words are different), the time complexity will be only 2N.

Most of the time, it will be much faster because of all the word repetitions.

Comment: No. His current complexity is not 4N. `words.count(word)` is O(N) and he does that N times, yielding a complexity O(N^2), given that N=`len(words)`.

Comment: you are absolutely right, I edit it, thanks